# Cursor key terminal input in Go

Tags: go, terminal

I am creating a Go application for usage in a terminal. The following  code asks a user to input text to the terminal.

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    for {
        fmt.Println("Please input something and use arrows to move along the text left and right")
        in := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
        _, err := in.ReadString('\n')
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that a user cannot use left and right arrows to go along the just inputted text in order to modify it. When he presses arrows, the console prints  `^[[D^[[C^[[A^[[B` signs.

The output:

```
Please input something and use arrows to move along the text left and right
hello^[[D^[[C^[[A^[[B
```

How to make arrow keys behave more user-friendly and let a human navigate along the just inputted text, using left and right arrows?

I guess, I should pay attention to libraries like [termbox-go](http://godoc.org/github.com/nsf/termbox-go) or [gocui](https://github.com/jroimartin/gocui)  but how to use them exactly for this purpose, I do not know.

Answer (score 3):

A simpler example would be [`carmark/pseudo-terminal-go`](https://github.com/carmark/pseudo-terminal-go), where you can put a [terminal in raw mode](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21752/what-s-the-difference-between-a-raw-and-a-cooked-device-driver) and benefit from the full up-down-left-right cursor moves.

From [`terminal.go#NewTerminal()`](https://github.com/carmark/pseudo-terminal-go/blob/master/terminal/terminal.go#L108-L112)

```
// NewTerminal runs a VT100 terminal on the given ReadWriter. If the ReadWriter is
// a local terminal, that terminal must first have been put into raw mode.
// prompt is a string that is written at the start of each input line (i.e.
// "> ").
func NewTerminal(c io.ReadWriter, prompt string) *Terminal
```

See [terminal/terminal.go](https://github.com/carmark/pseudo-terminal-go/blob/master/terminal/terminal.go) and [`terminal/terminal_test.go`](https://github.com/carmark/pseudo-terminal-go/blob/master/terminal/terminal_test.go), as well as [`MakeRaw()`](https://github.com/carmark/pseudo-terminal-go/blob/55c346b46a29c2728fed062bb52db3a76816ca83/terminal/util.go#L37-L54)

Comment: I cannot install this library. `$ go get github.com/carmark/pseudo-terminal-go` outputs
`package github.com/carmark/pseudo-terminal-go
 imports terminal: unrecognized import path "terminal"`

Comment: @MaximYefremov I agree. It was more to give an example of code regarding the implementation of a terminal, and the fact it needs to be put in raw mode.

Comment: It works great, you have to import "github.com/carmark/pseudo-terminal-go/terminal"

Comment: This package doesn't allow you to type unicode characters